# Unable to use foreach method on Firebase fetch data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm stuck during fetching Firebase data. How to read Firebase object?

the key like : `-KYl7Q_gcndAPqFC2eCn` makes me stuck to fetch it. How do I know that object name?

** This fetch is for public blog.

```
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  apiKey: "foobarbaz",
  authDomain: "whatever.com",
  databaseURL: "foo.com",
  storageBucket: "bar.com",
  messagingSenderId: "1234567890000"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

firebase.database().ref("pelanggan").on('value', function(snapshot) {
  var pelanggan = snapshot.val();
  console.log(pelanggan);
  var div_senarai_pelanggan = document.getElementById('div_senarai_pelanggan');

  console.log(key);
  var html = "";
  html = '<ol>';
  pelanggan.foreach(a, function(key, value) {
    console.log(key);
  })
  html += '</ol>';
  div_senarai_pelanggan.innerHTML = html;

});
```

Here's my [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/imranhamzah/0agwkngt/2/).

Comment: i would recommend changing your API key ASAP since you've now publicized it to the internet

Comment: @imjared: the API key in that configuration snippet just identifies a project, much like a URL does. All of this is publicly shareable, in fact: you will need to share it with your users to ensure they can access your app. See [Is it safe to expose Firebase apiKey to the public?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase stores your contents in object format. You should be able to see this in your `console.log()` call. `forEach()` is [a method specific to arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) so you wouldn't be able to call it on an object. You'll need to iterate over the collection of objects using

```
Object.keys( pelanggan ).forEach( function( key ) {
    console.log( pelanggan[ key ] );
});
```

If you want to use a variation of `.forEach()`, I'd recommend using [Lodash's implementation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#forEach) then you can do what you're trying to do with

```
_.forEach( pelanggan, function( item ) {
    console.log( item );
});
```

Comment: How to change my api key?